# Python PIL Black and White Image to 2D array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use the python PIL library to convert an image to black and white and then extract the pixels as a 2d array of 0's and 1's.

So far I am able to convert the image to black and white as follows:

```
bwImage = Image.open(imageFilePath)   
bwImage = bwImage.convert(mode="1", dither=Image.NONE)
```

But from here I don't know how to extract each pixel as a numeric value and enter it into the array. I have tried sum of the numpy functions like asarray() and array() but these don't seem to work for 1-bit images.

Comment: `array = np.array(bwImage, dtype=np.uint8)` works for me.

Comment: Thanks @HansHirse, that worked! I was missing the dtype argument.